# Pass script arguments as a pattern

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that requires a glob expression as a parameter. However I am having trouble using inputs as globs i.e say my input is

```
Shell_script '*.c'
```

and my code is iterating through an array of files and filtering them through pattern matching. In this case files which do not have the .c extension. (In this example, the first input could be any pattern otherwise)

```
    count=${#array[@]}
    for (( q = 0; q < count; q++ ));
    do
         if [[ ${array[q]}  == $1 ]]; then
              :
         else unset array[q]
         fi
    done
    .....
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `*.c` isn't a valid regex. Are you trying to filter a list of files ? it appears that what you are trying to use is some kind of glob pattern.

Comment: Yes Im trying to filter a list of files

Comment: Can't you just loop over the files using something like:  `for file in *.c
do
        #$file is your file
done
`

Comment: I'm trying to do it with *.c as an argument to the shell script

Comment: Why pass the glob as an argument, rather than pass **the matched files** as a list of arguments? That's the usual approach, and how, for instance `ls *.c` works.

Comment: BTW, shell arrays can be **sparse** -- so just because an array contains 5 items doesn't mean their indexes are numbers 0 through 4. Thus, the C-style `for` loop here isn't guaranteed to safely iterate through all array contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching array contents against a glob is entirely possible:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this array has noncontiguous indexes to demonstrate a potential bug in the original code
array=( [0]="hello.c" [3]="cruel.txt" [5]="world.c" )

glob=$1
for idx in "${!array[@]}"; do
  val=${array[$idx]}
  if [[ $val = $glob ]]; then
    echo "File $val matches glob expression $glob" >&2
  else
    echo "File $val does not match glob expression $glob; removing" >&2
    unset array[$idx]
  fi
done
```

---

Similarly, you can expand a glob against filesystem contents, though you'll want to clear IFS first to avoid string-splitting:

```
# here, the expectation is that your script would be invoked as: ./yourscript '*.c'

IFS=
for f in $1; do
  [[ -e $f || -L $f ]] || { echo "No file matching $f found" >&2; }
  echo "Iterating over file $f"
done
```

That said, in general, this is *extremely* unidiomatic, as opposed to letting the calling shell expand the glob before your script is started, and reading the list of matched files off your argument vector. Thus:

```
# written this way, your script can just be called ./yourscript *.c
for f; do
  [[ -e $f || -L $f ]] || { echo "No file matching $f found" >&2; }
  echo "Iterating over file $f"
done
```

Comment: why is it [[ $val = $glob]] and not [[ $val == $glob]]

Comment: @DarthVeder, because `==` isn't a valid operator in POSIX test. See the standards document at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, and it clearly documents the only valid string comparison operator as `=`; bash adds `==`, but that's an extension, and it's better habit to be accustomed to the standards-compliant, and thus widely compatible, approach.

Comment: If i switch the arguments in the if statement to:
if [[ $val == *.c ]] the glob statement works
with the example you shared above. I was returned an empty list

Comment: You're making two changes at once. Change the `==` to only `=` while leaving the `$glob` vs `*.c` unmodified, and you'll see that the former change is not the one with any effect.

Comment: ...the most likely explanation is that `$glob` is incorrectly assigned. Use `bash -x yourscript '*.c'` to trace its execution, and watch the assignment.

Comment: You were right changing == to only = had no effect.

I checked $glob using echo *.c is printing to the screen

Comment: Don't trust `echo` to tell you anything true. `printf '%q\n' "$glob"`

Comment: and, well, can you show a line emitted from that with `set -x` that shows a comparison that should be true instead being false?

Comment: When I called that printf statement. I recieved a list of empty characters ended by the *.c like:
''
''
''
...
*.c

Comment: so your `$glob` doesn't actually contain `*.c` -- that's not exactly surprising to me here. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104565/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-darth-veder).

Comment: at the bottom there is a \*.c and then the scope of the script is exited

Comment: The problem was in the recursive call. i had to concatenate a new argument string beginning with the directory and arguments $2 - .....

which is why glob was empty most of the time

Comment: @DarthVeder, obviously. If you were paying attention, you'd notice that that bug is among those I fixed in the copy of your code I pasted at you in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your list of files like this. If you run your script as
`./test.sh "*.c"`. Then inside your script you can do:

```
for file in $1
do
  #use your file
done
```

Comment: This is possible, but it's also a bad idea without some care (such as clearing IFS). Look what happens when the pattern contains a space.